# MLE for high dimensional $\theta$

Tags: maximum-likelihood, expectation-maximization, high-dimensional

I'm estimating a parameter $\theta$ in the context of covariance structure model given by $\Sigma(\theta)$. As an estimator, I use ML and computation is done by fmincon function in Matlab(using sqp algorithm). However, since the dimension of $\theta$ is very large, sometimes, more than 100, the result is very unstable even with sample size N=2000.

So, I'm wondering if there are alternative ways to obtain $\theta$. I considered EM althorithm, but since I cannot explicitly solve $\theta$, it seems to be difficult to use EM.

Comment: Could you use an alternative (EM suitable) distribution as an initial approximation and then obtain starting values from that?

Comment: As the starting value, I tried both the true value and random values, but the results are very similar. So, the problem should be in algorithm, I guess.